# Angular2 Material RadioButton or Select from booleans

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I have a form with 3 booleans. 
I would like to use either a Material select or Material radio button group to force only one of the booleans to be true. Can i do this in a clever way without using custom function calls, events or other tricks?

```
bnForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    isContinuous: [true],
    isDiscrete: [false],
    isHybrid: [false]
});
```

Is there a way to do something like this (it doesn't work)?

```
<form [formGroup]="bnForm">
    <mat-radio-group>
        <mat-radio-button [value]="isContinuous">Continuous</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button [value]="isDiscrete">Discrete</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button [value]="isHybrid">Hybrid</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</form>
```

Comment: This is basic HTML : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio

Comment: Can you refactor your form to use a single variable with 3 possible values? You could define an `enum` with the 3 values.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @ConnorsFan's comment, if the values are mutually exclusive you may prefer to do something like this - [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtrwkp?file=app%2Fradio-overview-example.html)

Markup

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-radio-group formControlName="type">
    <mat-radio-button value="Continuous">Continuous</mat-radio-button>
    <br><br>
    <mat-radio-button value="Discrete">Discrete</mat-radio-button>
    <br><br>
    <mat-radio-button value="Hybrid">Hybrid</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</form>
```

Code

```
export class RadioOverviewExample {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      type: ['Continuous']
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((simpleChanges: SimpleChanges) => {
      console.log(simpleChanges);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

please refer to this example.

https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples
[image]

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I can't comment. Becuase I don't have enough reputation.
someone has more than 50 reputation can add comment.

Comment: Then please elaborate your answer. As you can see, people are already downvoting you for the quality.